# How to pass null parameter to a function in POSTGRESQL?

Tags: java, function, postgresql, null, callable-statement

i have a question.
I have a function called

```
fn_Sell(id integer, idCreditCard integer, description varchar)
```

thats an exameple, is not the all function, but i want to pass NULL, in idCreditCard, the field acepts null, but when i pass null value,

```
it said UNKONW kind of parameter (integer, UNKONW , varchar)
```

i think is cause of integer is not a null type of value.... what can i do?

y use callable statement in java, and for the second parameter i pass null

Comment: You have to show us `fn_Sell` but offhand I'd guess you need `someStatement.setNull("idCreditCard", Types.INTEGER)` and you are trying `someStatement.setInt(null)`

Comment: Where are you calling the function? Java? Show us the code where you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you are passing in String "NULL" instead of NULL value. Both are different. Check what is passed through.